# Prove that if x is odd and y is even, then gcd(x+y,x-y)=gcd(x,y)

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility

It is trivial to prove that gcd(x,y) divides gcd(x+y,x-y). How is it possible to prove gcd(x+y,x-y) divides gcd(x,y)? I don´t know how to use the fact that x is odd and y is even. Can anybody help me prove the statement?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose $d\,|\,\gcd (x+y,x-y)$.  Then $d\,|\,(x+y+x-y)=2x$.  Now, the parity assumptions tell us that both $x\pm y$ are odd so $d$ must be odd.  Hence $d\,|\,2x\implies d\,|\,x$.

Can you finish from here?

Comment: What I see is that we could do an analogous reasoning for y and say that d divides y and, together with d divides x, we could say that d divides gcd(x,y). How can I conclude? I am stuck.

Comment: Well, $\gcd(x+y,x-y)$ is a divisor of $\gcd(x+y,x-y)$.

Comment: I can't understand your confusion. In my post, I proved that any $d$ which divides $\gcd(x+y,x-y)$ also must divide $\gcd(x,y)$.  So, just take $d=\gcd(x+y,x-y)$ and you are done.

Comment: Oh, now I see it. Sorry a lot! I read your comment wrong! Now I understand!  Thank you very much !!

Comment: No problem, glad to help.